# Select ID from Picker

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am getting values in picker from an API, text and Value are two fields as I declared ! I am able to see values in it ! I want that whenever I select item from It, I am able to fetch respective value of that field !

```
async void CallInspectionMaster()
            {
                string Url = "192.168.xx.xx/api/QMSin/GetInspectionMasterList";
                var data = await Url.GetJsonAsync<List<MyClass>>();
                InspectionMasterPicker.ItemsSource = data;
                InspectionMasterPicker.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("Text");
                Binding selecteditemx = new Binding("InspectionMaster");
                selecteditemx.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                selecteditemx.Source = InspectionMasterPicker;
             }



 public class MyClass
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

I have to display text but fetch value so I can pass it other functions ! How do do that ?

Comment: Text is already coming I need associated Value !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign a handler to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event

```
InspectionMasterPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += PickerSelect;
```

then create the handler

```
protected void PickerSelect(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var item = (MyClass)InspectionMasterPicker.SelectedItem;

    ...
}
```

there is a [complete example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.picker?view=xamarin-forms#remarks) included in the docs

Comment: This gives me text of that selected item which I am displaying but I need Value associated with it !  See this ! {"Text":"ODYSSEY CRAFT (PVT.) LTD.","Value":"C20171"},{"Text":"Rio Fashion Wear Limited","Value":"C20172"}]

Comment: this was not working ! var item =(MyClass)InspectionMasterPicker.Items[InspectionMasterPicker.SelectedIndex];         
                                                                                                                                        
 So I wrote this !                                                                                                              
 var item =InspectionMasterPicker.Items[InspectionMasterPicker.SelectedIndex];

Comment: item should be of type MyClass, which has Value and Text properties

Comment: But that was giving me an error with red color and not allowing me to use it !

Comment: “Error with red color” is hot helpful.  What is the actual error message?

Comment: cann't convert string to  projectname.models.MyClass

Comment: according to your code your ItemsSource is List<MyClass>

Comment: MyClass was used to bind it  with Picker